# comma before "which" clause

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> This is important for corporations to gain the trust of their customers which increases the profits of companies.
>
> This is important **way** for corporations to gain the trust of their customers`,` which increases the profits of companies.

1) Should I include comma? I think so because it is non-defining clause. If it is not please inform me what is this called?

2) Is it wrong or unclear, if I do **not** include "way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need that comma before "which." Your second question is a little harder to answer without some context, but assuming "this" refers to a way for "corporates" (maybe "corporations" or "companies"?) to gain the trust of their customers, then you should include "way" – but you also need "an" before "important."

Since "corporate" is an adjective and "company" is a noun, I'd also recommend switching "corporates" to "companies" and "the profits of companies" to "corporate profits."

---